# How to create a default for a generic parameter of a type?

Tags: typescript

How would you build a type like the following:

```
type T<X extends Z = Z> = ...
```

so that you can consume it as `T` instead of always having to provide a parameter `T<X>`?

Specifically, when using the same types for the `Z = Z` part, I get the error

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)
```

Here is the exact code:

```
export type QuestionType<
  TAnswerMap extends GenericAnswerMapType = GenericAnswerMapType
> =
  | RadioQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
  | DateQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
  | DropdownQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
  | BooleanQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
  | TextQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
  | ListQuestionType<TAnswerMap>
```

and the TS error

```
../shared/constants/questionnaire.tsx:116:13 - error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

116 export type QuestionType<
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What specifically are you looking for, other than perhaps [documentation for generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)?

Comment: This is also covered in the TypeScript GitHub repo's [issue #2175](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175).

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't specific enough. Updated OP.

Comment: @DakotaMethvin thanks for the link. It is a rather complex thread that I don't really understand and could not parse an answer from. I'm more at the grade 5 level here, unfortunately.

Comment: Typescript 3.9.7 happily accepts the code in the OP on my machine. I can't reproduce the error you claim.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's very interesting. The version this was encountered on is `^4.1.3`, which is higher. My situation is so complex right now with all of the subtypes and I've never seen this issue; too complex for me to summarize in a concise question. I'll add some more code to the question and see if that helps.